# In C, check for the offset in a character string and count the number of bytes

Tags: c, byte, ascii, bitmask

Further help on my assignment I asked about earlier. After reading a character string from stdin, it checks for any non-ascii characters. Any it finds will display it's value in hexadecimal and the zero offset. I got it to display the hexadecimal just fine, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to display the offset. This is my current code for it as of asking this question, showing only the relevant lines.

```
#define MASK 0x80

auto int inChar;

if ((inChar & MASK) == MASK)
{
    printf("NON-ASCII INPUT: %x detected at offset %#x \n", inChar, inChar);
    nonascii = 1;
}
```

There is another thing I need help with, hopefully this will be easier to answer though. If the line read has nothing but ASCII, it is to write out as such and display the total number of bytes read. I know how to do this with integers and multiplication by simply counting the number of times a do while is done, but the professor seems to want us to do it in a more direct manner.

This is my code for that as of writing.

```
if (nonascii == 0)
    printf("The input stream was pure ASCII with a total of %d bytes read", (numBytes &= inChar));
```

Much thanks to those who help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

**inChar** contains the *value* of the character read; it does not carry information about where in the string the character is, therefore it is not possible to figure out the offset from this variable.

The place to look at is wherever you fill **inChar** with the current character; unfortunately, we do not see that part of the code. Most likely, at that point, you are extracting the value from a certain index in the string and you should just use the same index variable for displaying the offset. Another possibility is that you are extracting the value from the string by moving a pointer within the string. In that case, the way to extract the offset is by using *pointer arithmetic*: say that you have pointer **string** that points to the beginning of the string and **stringIter** that points at the currently processed character, then looking at how far the pointers are from each other will tell you your offset in the string: **stringIter - string**.

Answer (score 1):

inChar is a character, not an offset.  Offset means the array index of where the character was found in the string, and you should probably print it as decimal using the %d formatter.

The simplest way to display a string's length is with the strlen() function.  But if you're not allowed to use that, then the length of the string is the array index + 1 when you fall out of the loop.